# Enable template Footer and Page number in PowerPoint 2011

Tags: macos, office-for-mac, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

My PowerPoint 2011 for Mac template has master pages with Page number and Footer text fields.

When adding normal presentation pages, these are missing from the page. They are just not there.

Here's what I tried to bring them back:

- Going to *Insert* > *Header and Footer* and enabling the Footer and Page number options. The text from the Master is visible there. After I hit OK, the fields still don't appear. Returning to *Insert* > *Header and Footer* shows the options still disabled.
- Using the option *Layout* > *Reset Layout to Default Settings*. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to add the footer:

- select the first master view slide on the left sidebar (usually its the first one)
- then go to "slide master" tab at the top, then under master elements click the little
  arrow  and select footer.  This will make the footer appear.
- You can now go to insert > header and footer to set the actual text